# Error when installing List-SomeUtils from cpan

Tags: perl, cpan, cpanm

I seem to get an error when trying to install from cpan

```
cpan List::SomeUtils
```

Perl v5.14.2

I have also downloaded direct from metacpan and doing a `perl Makefile.pl` and `make` but `make test` fails with the same error. Also with cpanm.

My Google foo is not coming up with anything useful for this one, so not sure where to go (this is required by another package, so not a simple workaround). I could try a force, but not sure how much of an issue it could be ?

```
Undefined subroutine &Module::Implementation::implementation_for
```

```
t/Functions.t .......... 7/? Undefined subroutine &Module::Implementation::implementation_for called at /usr/src/List-SomeUtils-0.58/blib/lib/List/SomeUtils.pm line 94.
    # Child (pairwise) exited without calling finalize()

#   Failed test 'pairwise'
#   at /opt/perl/lib/site_perl/5.14.2/Test/Builder.pm line 279.
# Tests were run but no plan was declared and done_testing() was not seen.
# Looks like your test exited with 29 just after 31.
t/Functions.t .......... Dubious, test returned 29 (wstat 7424, 0x1d00)
Failed 1/31 subtests 
t/Import.t ............. ok   
t/pp-only.t ............ Undefined subroutine &Module::Implementation::implementation_for called at t/pp-only.t line 10.
t/pp-only.t ............ Dubious, test returned 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
No subtests run 

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/Functions.t        (Wstat: 7424 Tests: 31 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  31
  Non-zero exit status: 29
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/pp-only.t          (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
Files=5, Tests=34,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.06 usr  0.01 sys +  0.65 cusr  0.02 csys =  0.74 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 2/5 test programs. 1/34 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I have got around this with

```
cpan Module::Implementation
```

which it seems to require.

Comment: Created [ticket](https://github.com/houseabsolute/List-SomeUtils/issues/11)